# JavaFX Split Menu Button Arrow Trigger Event save clicked item in string

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a SplitMenuButton, and I can't seem to find a way to trigger an event when the user clicks the arrow next to the button.

I would like to select item from dropdown(when mouse clicked on that item), display that in splitmenubutton and store value of that item in string to send to database.

I am not sure which event can do that, and I can not find any info on this either.

Comment: Add `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`s to the individual `MenuItem`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like.

```
for (final MenuItem item : smb.getItems()) {
        item.setOnAction((event) -> {               
            System.out.println("Selected!");
        });
    }
```